# Slow response times: Laravel 5.2 in Docker container

Tags: php, macos, laravel, docker, boot2docker

When running Laravel 5.2 within a PHP-7 docker container I'm getting response times in `300ms - 400ms`.

That is extremely slow although if I'm just echoing out `phpinfo()` on the same container the response time is `15ms - 50ms` is anyone experiencing these slow response times with Laravel in a Docker container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, problem solved.

On a local development environment using Docker 1.10 with the VirtualBox driver and a volume mounted to the host system (that would be Boot2Docker VM and OSX) the performance is incredibly woeful, as described above `300ms - 600ms`.

Use the same configuration without the mounted volumes `20ms - 30ms` response times. My assumption is that because Laravel has intensive disk I/O due to the large amount of files it loads on each request this is impacted by how VirtualBox shares folders between the host and a VM.

Issue is not a Docker or Laravel, its a VirtualBox VM issue.

UPDATE:

Comparing differing environments in a docker

Note: the below are without `artisan optimize --force` or `artisan config:cache`

- **HHVM** 13ms - 31ms (TCP port 9000)
- **HHVM** 12ms - 22ms (Unix socket)
- **PHP-7 FPM** 42ms - 73ms (TCP port 9000)
- **PHP-7 FPM** 38ms - 55ms (Unix socket)

---

## WOW...!

**`HHVM with artisan optimisations + unix sockets: 8ms - 12ms`**

---

**PHP-7 FPM** with artisan optimisations + unix sockets: 38ms - 42ms

Take a look at HHVM with optimizations and unix sockets. It's very fast.

Comment: VirtualBox on OSX is *insanely* slow for mounted host folders unless you use NFS for them. No idea why, but life was much better when I figured that out.

Comment: how do you set that up? with Boot2Docker?

Comment: I use Vagrant + Virtualbox, not Docker. `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/srv/web", type: "nfs", :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1']` in my Vagrant file did the trick, but I've no idea about Boot2Docker for passing data to Virtualbox.

Comment: I cant not use docker... its simply too powerful. I can live with slow responses in development

Comment: Vagrant / homestead is so sloppy compared to docker

Answer (score 5):

For the benefit of anyone else that stumbles on this question via Google, Docker for Mac now supports [user guided caching](https://blog.docker.com/2017/05/user-guided-caching-in-docker-for-mac/#h.gwo2at29v042) for volumes.

> Different applications require different levels of consistency. Full
>   consistency is sometimes essential, and remains the default. However,
>   to support cases where temporary inconsistency is an acceptable price
>   to pay for improved performance, Docker 17.04 CE Edge includes new
>   flags for the -v option:
>
> - consistent: Full consistency. The container runtime and the host
>     maintain an identical view of the mount at all times.  This is the
>     default, as described above.
> - cached: The host’s view of the mount is
>     authoritative. There may be delays before updates made on the host are
>     visible within a container.

Enabling cached mode for my Laravel app was as simple as updating the volume references in docker-compose.yml.

Before:

```
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
```

After:

```
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www:cached
```

Having made that change and recreated my containers I’m seeing performance that much more closely matches what I’d expect from non-virtualised local server. Previously a simple request was taking 1.3s to complete and that’s dropped to 0.35s. Despite the warning that host changes may not immediately be visible in the container I’ve yet to notice any issues with propagation.

There’s also an ongoing GH issue about [Docker Mac FS performance](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1592) with some useful notes.

Comment: can confirm this. **without** `:cached` the response time was ~1.5 sec, **with** `:cached` is ~0.4secs. Thanks for the tip!